# Heroku Neo4j Issue

Tags: python, heroku, neo4j, py2neo

I have my neo4j python application using py2neo.
It is working corretly on local but when i deploy it to heroku it is giving error 
**py2neo.rest.SocketError
SocketError: gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known')**

I am not sure what is the issue. 
what should be the correct issue I am using url for db service as 
**graph_db = neo4j.GraphDatabaseService("http://xyz.hosted.neo4j.org:7480/db/data/")**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Configure the authentication as indicated here:
http://packages.python.org/py2neo/neo4j.html#authentication

Use `heroku config` to note the username and password in the URL.

For example (obviously modified):

```
$ heroku config
=== secure-caverns-9214 Config Vars
NEO4J_URL: http://username:password@17d0afad4.hosted.neo4j.org:7755
PATH:      bin:node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```